# windows 8 app CSS listview change inlined styles

Tags: javascript, windows-8, stylesheet

hi community i´ve a huge problem, i use a listview to show tiles in snapped view, so when i need to change the size of my div container only need change the size of my image (nested in div container), and reload the App and the new size will take for the all tiles, but in the DOM explorer found that autocreate a new div only in the first tile:

```
<div tabindex="0" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

so this tile dont have an id or class but take a style from:

```
inlined {
height: 139px;
left: 0px;
position: relative;
top: 0px;
width: 1206px;
}
```

So i need to change de height size for height size that i need, but dont know how redefine a style in line, and dont know why create this style and this div if dont use and i dont create it, also this css style dont made refence to a  UI.Ligth.css or base.css  or other css rule but if a change the parameter height size (in the dom explorer) take the size that need, i dont know how redefine inlined style, i made a style in my css with the name inlined but dont work, even this style autogenerate dont made reference to any ID or class, cause this style dont use . or #

this is the template that used for made the listview:

```
 <div id="article_beneficioslistView_small"                                 
 data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" 
 data-win-options="{ 
 itemDataSource: beneficiosData.dataSource, 
 itemTemplate: beneficiosTemplate, 
 selectionMode: 'none', 
 tapBehavior: 'invoke', 
 swipeBehavior: 'none',
 layout: { type: WinJS.UI.ListLayout } 
 }">
</div>
```

so i hope you somebody help me cause a really need it, ive been made crazy try to fix.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Grid layout with vw(viewport width) and vh(viewport height) units for your layouts, It helps making your app responsive.
you can use media queries to define sizes of your list views for full screen and snapped views

```
@media screen and (-ms-view-state: snapped) 
{
#article_beneficioslistView_small img
{
//css here
}
}
```